# What's the difference between bluetooth-soc chips and bluetooth modules?

Tags: embedded, bluetooth, soc, system-on-chip

I'm currently shopping for a Bluetooth transceiver to play around with.
After doing some research, I think there's a bit of crucial terminology that I'm missing.

Specifically, there's two products that I'm looking at:

- [BC127](https://www.bluecreation.com/listing.php?cPath=22) 
- [Csr8675](http://www.csr.com/products/csr8675)

Are they intended for different purposes?

From what I can tell, they're pretty similar in functionality and both have mass production in mind.
Yet the BC127 is 2 times the physical size of the Csr chip, as well as being 2 times the price for a single unit.

And on their respective webpages, the Bc127 is referred to as a module while Csr chips are referred to as 'audio system-on-chip' or 'audio platform'?

Is there any intrinsic difference between the two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the CSR chip is referred to as an "audio platform", is that in addition to the Bluetooth capability, it also includes a DSP (Digital Signal Processor), stereo DAC and ADC, and a battery charger.  It is clearly intended to be used for products such as a wireless headset or headphone.

The BC127 module also has a DSP and DAC, but no ADC  (so it is intended for output only audio applications, like a wireless headphone).  It includes an antenna; the CSR does not.

Both are dual-mode: classic Bluetooth and BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy), and support many other protocols besides audio.

The CSR would be a bad choice for you by itself, as it comes in either a 112-ball BGA, or WLSCP package, neither of which are hobbyist friendly.  You would need to buy some sort of development board or breakout board; [theirs is $800](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/rf-if-and-rfid/rf-evaluation-and-development-kits-boards/3539644?k=csr8675).

The BC127 is a better choice, but once again, the module by itself with castellated pins with a 0.8 mm pitch is not particularly easy to work with.

I suggest you look at SparkFun's [offering of Bluetooth breakout boards](https://www.sparkfun.com/search/results?term=bluetooth); while you can buy the BC127 module by itself (cheaper than Digi-Key BTW), you are better off buying [a breakout board](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11927) which is easier to work with.

[image]

Comment: Woah, the csr has a battery charger built in!? Might I ask where I can read about that? I looked through various documentations but don't recall ever seeing that.

Comment: @House3272 it's mentioned right on the page you linked to in your question, after Audio and Power Management.  You'll have to get the datasheet for the details.  The CSR is really only appropriate if you are planning making a product; if you just want to get familiar with Bluetooth and audio, the BC127 (and others that you can buy breakout boards for) are a much better choice.

Comment: well that's not embarasssing....thanks hahah. They updated the page since I bookmarked it. If I may just bother you some more, do you off the hand know any other breakout boards with similar functionality(dual-mode w apt-x support)? I could only find that sparkfun one.

Answer (score 1):

Without looking at the specific functions of these two devices (and feathures that are available will always change), the fundamental difference is that a module has all of the RF self-contained, tested and type approved.

If you use a SoC with wireless, you will need to:

- understand *some* level of RF layout
- Provide an antenna (ceramic, wire or track)
- Often provide other passives
- Submit the product for type-approvals testing

However, the SoC might be cheaper overall for production, and maybe smaller. If this is a one-off build, the module provides a tested solution, the SoC requires you to do the testing of the radio - unless you find an eval board for the SoC (i.e. another module).

If you add an extewrnal antenna for a module, generally that will require sumitting for type approval over again.

Answer (score 0):

The CSR is a bare IC! No passives, no RF section.

The BC is a module. It has an RF section on board, the antenna, the RF shield, maybe some passive capacitors. Half of those modules have a chip or pcb antenna built in. The other only need the bare antenna.

The first needs to have everything implemented on your custom pcb. The second could, with power and maybe data, be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

First off all, please forgive me for replying to such an old question -- I don't know if that's bad etiquette on EE SE.

It should be noted that the BC127 is, at its core, a CSR8670 with a friendly API built atop it.

You're paying for the RF section, and more crucially, the API that BlueCreation built on top of the CSR chip. CSR themselves are very tight lipped about their APIs and developer documentation, and now that they're owned by Qualcomm, I doubt that has gotten any better.